# Cannot make Relative Path, Rewrite Rules and Routes behave the way I intended

Tags: php, apache, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting, routes

### Background

I am writing a web project with PHP without framework. I used various packages to write in MVC pattern. For the routing part (I used [League/Route](https://route.thephpleague.com/4.x/)), I have to set some rewriting rules on Apache server for the routes to work.

The company's server is set up in a way that all application codes sit outside of the document root, and alias is used to internally redirect to the application. This leads to a lot of trouble in terms of relative paths, routes and URL rewriting.

I'm going to break down the problems into steps, and try to understand one at a time. If you want to see the overall issue I'm having, please refer to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58774600/multiple-apps-multiple-versions-of-the-app-under-the-same-domain-how-to-config)

### PART 1

The router compares `$_SERVER["REQUEST_URI"]` value to routes defined to figure out which action it maps to. Here are routes:

```
$router->map("GET", "/", Hello1Controller::class);
$router->map("GET", "/hello2", Hello2Controller::class);
```

Here is the navigation bar, just something to demonstrate the routing:

```
<li><a href="/">Hello 1</a></li>
<li><a href="/hello2">Hello 2</a></li>
```

Here are the document root and rewrite rule in httpd.conf:

```
DocumentRoot "/usr/local/var/www/app/public"
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php$1 [L]
```

I have a template.twig sitting **outside** of the document root (not in public directory), and within template.twig I try to reference a css file:

```
<link href="css/style.css" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet"/>
```

This css file is in `public/css/style.css`, so it's inside the document root.

Now I try to access `https://localhost`, and the URL is rewritten to /index.php, triggering the front controller. The front controller then maps the REQUEST_URI (/) to Hello1Controller, which renders the template.twig. If we click "hello 2" on the navbar, it successfully navigates to that page.

**ISSUE**: relative path in resource reference not working:
A GET request is issued for each resource referenced in the template. `RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f` is going to test whether the referenced resource is a file or not. But `%{REQUEST_FILENAME}` turns out to be just the relative path with a `/` in front (made it relative to root I guess), not the full path after it's figured out. And this will obviously not be a file, resulting in the rewrite rule being applied to a regular file reference and sent to the front controller. You can see this from the log:

```
[rewrite:trace2] init rewrite engine with requested uri /css/style.css, referer: http://localhost/
[rewrite:trace3] applying pattern '^(.*)$' to uri '/css/style.css', referer: http://localhost/
[rewrite:trace4] RewriteCond: input='/css/style.css' pattern='!-f' => matched, referer: http://localhost/
[rewrite:trace2] rewrite '/css/style.css' -> '/index.php/css/style.css', referer: http://localhost/
[rewrite:trace2] local path result: /index.php/css/style.css, referer: http://localhost/
[rewrite:trace2] prefixed with document_root to /usr/local/var/www/app/public/index.php/css/style.css, referer: http://localhost/
```

And notice the requested uri is `"/css/style.css"`, but in code I used relative path `css/style.css`. This makes me think relative path is relative to the current "position" in url. Not sure whether it's before or after rewrite, but in this case result is the same--relative to either the root (because there is nothing in the path part of the uri), or index.php (which is in the same directory as root). Both resulting in the `"/css/style.css"` we see, instead of `/usr/local/var/www/app/public/css/style.css`.

Now that if this rewrite rule is being applied in a per-directory context, then it works: `%{REQUEST_FILENAME}` is now the relative path appended with the directory, making it a full path leading to the file.

```
DocumentRoot "/usr/local/var/www/app/public"
<Directory "/usr/local/var/www/app/public">
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteRule ^ /index.php [L]
</Directory>
```

(RewriteRule had to be tweaked a bit in order for hello2 to work. This shouldn't affect the relative path)

```
[rewrite:trace3] [perdir /usr/local/var/www/app/public/] strip per-dir prefix: /usr/local/var/www/app/public/css/style.css -> css/style.css, referer: http://localhost/
[rewrite:trace3] [perdir /usr/local/var/www/app/public/] applying pattern '^(.*)$' to uri 'css/style.css', referer: http://localhost/
[rewrite:trace4] [perdir /usr/local/var/www/app/public/] RewriteCond: input='/usr/local/var/www/app/public/css/style.css' pattern='!-f' => not-matched, referer: http://localhost/
[rewrite:trace1] [perdir /usr/local/var/www/app/public/] pass through /usr/local/var/www/app/public/css/style.css, referer: http://localhost/
```

**Question**: Is this just the default behavior of relative path in rewriting rules? per-directory or .htaccess is always required for it to work?

Also here is the observation I made about relative path. Please correct me if I'm wrong:

The relative paths in the client-side code (in html, css, or the twig templates, in which the included resources are not resolved until passed to the client side):

- If the file referencing a resource with relative path is inside the document root, then relative path works intuitively: it's relative to the current file.
- If the file referencing a resource with relative path is outside of the document root (e.g. in a template file being rendered and sent to the client side), then the path is not relative to the current file. It is relative to the current url. That is, a ".." will go back one level in the url. This is preventing me to use relative path in those files.

### PART 2

Now I change the server setting so that the document root is no longer inside the application, but instead app sits entirely inside document root. I soft linked app/ into www/

```
DocumentRoot "/usr/local/var/www"
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^/?$ /app/public/index.php [L]
<Directory "/usr/local/var/www/app/public">
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteRule ^ /index.php [L]
</Directory>
```

In order for `https://localhost` to internally redirect to my application, I added another rewrite rule.
Now the resource referencing is not working again:

```
[rewrite:trace2] init rewrite engine with requested uri /css/style.css, referer: http://localhost/
[rewrite:trace3] applying pattern '^/?$' to uri '/css/style.css', referer: http://localhost/
[rewrite:trace1] pass through /css/style.css, referer: http://localhost/
[core:trace3] request authorized without authentication by access_checker_ex hook: /css/style.css, referer: http://localhost/
[core:info] AH00128: File does not exist: /usr/local/var/www/css/style.css, referer: http://localhost/
```

The per-directory definition is not even processed. I tried different variations of the rewrite rules, including adding and removing [L], changing the order of two rewrite rules hoping the per-directory one gets executed first, wrapping the first rewrite rule with its own  directive, etc... None of these worked.
The "hello 2" tab on the navbar isn't working as well due to the same reason––per-directory rewrite rules are not processed at all.

### PART 3

Next step is to move the application entirely outside of the document root, and use alias to internally redirect to the app.

Comment: Try replacing the RewriteRule line(s) with `RewriteRule . /index.php [QSA,L]`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Welcome to Stackoverflow!

Looking at what you have there, it doesn't appear like you need to do what you have written in your answer.

if your project sits in: `/usr/local/var/www/app`
and your document root is: `/usr/local/var/www/app/public`

It looks like you are a little confused between your projects root folder and the HTTP server `DocumentRoot`.

The HTTP Server `DocumentRoot`, is the folder that apache should treat at the root. i.e. when you go to `http://myapp.com/index.php`, it will look in the `DocumentRoot` for `index.php`.

Assuming you have configured your site as a `VirtualHost`, as most do, your vhost config would look something like this:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerAdmin admin@myapp.local
    DocumentRoot "/usr/local/var/www/app/public"

    <Directory /usr/local/var/www/app>
        AllowOverride all
    </Directory>
    ServerName myapp.local

    ErrorLog "/var/log/myapp.local-error_log"
    CustomLog "/var/log/myapp.local-access_log" common
</VirtualHost>
```

Then in your `.htaccess` file that sits in the `DocumentRoot`: `/usr/local/var/www/app/public` you would have:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule .* /index.php$0 [PT]
```

You should also use a preceding slash in your HTML to refer to the css file, as the `/` will ensure that the path is relative to your `DocumentRoot`, which is where your css folder is.

The key thing here is that the only files that need to be in the DocumentRoot, are your `.htaccess` file, your index.php file and your assets. Your application will then refer to the code in the "app" folder by including files using the previous directory operator `../` in most cases/frameworks this would be something like `include('../bootstrap.php');`.

Comment: Hi Adam. Thanks for answering. I think what you suggested is for part one. The !-d might actually fix the resource reference part. I will need to test it out. For part 2 the document root is in /usr/local/var/www and app directory sits inside it. I needed to implement the way I suggested in my own answer in order to make it work. Of course there might be other ways out there. Your suggestion to precede a slash in the reference url is going to work if the docroot is exactly the app's public directory, but I don't think otherwise (especially if the project is entirely outside of the docroot).

Comment: You should distinguish the difference between the project root and the document root. The document root is the public directory as far as Apache is concerned and so you should always set the document root to that. I’ll update my answer in a couple of hours with a sample configuration that I would use for apache vhost

Comment: I've updated my answer to better explain the document root and have provided a sample config for an apache virtualhost. This should get your app working the way you expect it. If you take my recommendations, then there is no part 2 or part 3 as everything is looked after -- the solutions that you are applying only matter for when you have multiple versions of the same app running under a single domain, which isn't the case in your project.

Comment: You are absolutely right and I understood. The way I presented this question is probably a little confusing, since I tried to break it down into steps and solve one by one. Step 2 has no practical meaning. It is only an intermediate stage. Part 3 is the ultimate goal I want to achieve. You can see more details in [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58774600/multiple-apps-multiple-versions-of-the-app-under-the-same-domain-how-to-config). I stopped providing details here because I didn't want to make the question even longer. But really thank you for reading this lengthy question!

Answer (score 1):

Well I found a solution for Part 2:

```
    DocumentRoot "/usr/local/var/www"
    <Directory "/usr/local/var/www">
        RewriteEngine On
        RewriteRule ^$ app/public/ [L]
        RewriteRule (.*) app/public/$1 [L]
    </Directory>

    <Directory "/usr/local/var/www/app/public">
        RewriteEngine On
        RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
        RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
        RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]
    </Directory>
```

We need to have a per-directory rewrite rule at the root level to append the app's path to the docroot, before it's evaluated by the per-directory directives at app level.

This isn't anything official that I read, but rather something I see from experiment:
The path part of uri (after any previous rewrite rules have been applied) has to match the one specified in the "Directory" directive in order for it to execute. So at the beginning we are at the document root, so the root level per-directory directive executes. It appends the app/public part before the uri, so now the uri path contains the whole path leading to the app's public directory. Thus, the app's per-directory directives can be executed.

Part 3 can be resolved in similar fashion, with the addition of alias.
[This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58794392/8927840) provides an example for it.

---

Note: Part 2 implementation has no practical meaning and should be avoided in real production. It is just an intermediate step I took to solve the ultimate problem. Only your public folder (the one containing static content), if at all, should live inside the document root.

Comment: This is not a very good place to be because now your application files are exposed within the document root. It looks like the solution that you have quoted is meant for instances where you want to run multiple versions of the same app under a single domain. Take a look at my answer as setting it up like that should ensure that your css is included properly and that your code is not exposed in the document root.

Comment: @AdamCopley You are right. I have added a note to explain that.