# Multiple apps, multiple versions of the app under the same domain. How to configure apache server, routes and relative paths to make it work?

Tags: php, apache, mod-rewrite, deployment, routes

My team's server is set up in such as way: We have one domain name, which seems like already a subdomain of the company's domain. We want to host multiple applications under this one domain. We'd even like to have a production version and staging version for each of the apps on the server.

Document root is an empty folder. Applications sit outside of the document root.
we are trying to use the first token in the URL path to find out which app we try to access, then somehow redirect to it (internally or externally).

Here is a structure equivalent to how the directories are organized.

```
/usr/local/var/www  <- Document Root
/usr/local/var/app1 <- application 1
------------------/public/index.php
------------------/public/css
/usr/local/var/app2 <- application 2
/usr/local/var/app1.stg <- application 1 staging version, code is exactly the same as application1
/usr/local/var/app2.stg <- application 2 staging version, code is exactly the same as application2
```

Here are the relevant settings in httpd.conf

```
DocumentRoot /usr/local/var/www
<Directory "/usr/local/var/www">
    AllowOverride None
    Require all granted
</Directory>
Alias "/app1" "/usr/local/var/app1"
Alias "/app2" "/usr/local/var/app2"

<VirtualHost *:80>
   # rewriting rules to make the routing work
   # There is only one vhost so it can actually be removed
</VirtualHost>
```

When we access `https://sub.domain.com/app1`, we expect to go to app1
When we access `https://sub.domain.com/app1.stg`, we expect to go to app1.stg

The applications are written in PHP. This server configuration means we have to include the "path to the application" in the routes and rewrite rules, and use the "full absolute path" in all the resource references.
For example, a route will look like

```
$router->map("GET", "/app1/action", SomeController);
```

A css reference will be: (even though relative path is given, it behaves just like a relative path to the DocRoot (with "/" in front). You can see it in this detailed [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58760193/cannot-make-relative-path-rewrite-rules-and-routes-behave-the-way-i-intended))

```
<link href="app1/public/css/style.css" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet"/>
```

These will be sufficient to make both apps work, but the staging version is not going to work, because it contains EXACTLY THE SAME copy of code (which is how it's intended to be, to test out in staging environment, then push to production environment).
If I want both versions to work, I have to code the paths dynamically, namely using CONTEXT_DOCUMENT_ROOT or some other server variable to figure out which app version it's in, and have two copies of routes, one starting with app1, the other app1.stg. I also have to have separate rewriting rule for each version.

### QUESTION

With the server setup restriction applied (one domain name, distinguish apps with the way I described, etc..), is it possible to use only relative paths, write routes with respective to only the app itself? Some like:

```
<link href="css/style.css" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet"/>

$router->map("GET", "/action", SomeController);
```

In other words, I have to change the server setup within the constraints, so that the app can be written in a way without caring how the server is set up.

I know one way is to use different ports for each app/version, but apparently the server admin doesn't like the idea.

I've broken down the problem into steps in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58760193/cannot-make-relative-path-rewrite-rules-and-routes-behave-the-way-i-intended). It's quite long but if you are willing to follow through, it should provide much more details.

---

If the question is not clear enough, the [per-user directory](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/howto/public_html.html) looks quite like what I want to achieve. But instead of user directory, I want the app directory in place of it. Of course I never used per-user directory so I dont know if it actually behaves the way I think it does.

---

So I understand that we can have multiple hostnames in /etc/hosts mapped to one IP address. Can I just use that hostname as the ServerName in apache config, and access in the browser by typing that hostname? The website is for internal usage so should only be accessed within company's network.

In /etc/hosts:

```
123.45.67.89 app1.team-server-name app2.team-server-name
```

In httpd.conf:

```
<VirtualHost>
    ServerName app1.team-server-name
    DocumentRoot /usr/local/var/app1/public
</VirtualHost>
<VirtualHost>
    ServerName app2.team-server-name
    DocumentRoot /usr/local/var/app2/public
</VirtualHost>
```

Answer (score 1):

This is quite the lengthy question, thank you for providing so much detail.

I would opt for a different approach than you are currently attempting.  Instead of trying to serve each of these applications out of a folder, set up each of them as a domain based vhost.  Use something like app1.local or whatever for the hostname and be sure to add the entries to your /etc/hosts file under 127.0.0.1. Make sure the listen directive for these vhosts is on the loopback (127.0.0.1:80).  Each of these apps should function as if they were installed at the document root of their own server.  All the CSS should assume its at 'css/style.css' relative to /.

Now that you have all of the apps setup on the loopback, you can setup a reverse proxy from the vhost listening on the public interface to proxy all of the application locations to their appropriate loopback vhost after you remove the /app1 prefix from the request.

I haven't used Apache 2.x for a very long time, but the concepts are the same as nginx.

```
location  /foo {
  rewrite /foo/(.*) /$1  break;
  proxy_pass         http://app1.local;
  proxy_redirect     off;
  proxy_set_header   Host $host;
}
```

The biggest issue with this approach is that the applications that are being proxied either need to use relative paths everywhere, or they need to have some kind of configurable prefix that is prepended to the urls.  Most frameworks will support the prefix option.  For Example: https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/urls This prefix can be used for asset (css/js/jpg) loading as well, but only from files that execute PHP.

Comment: Thanks for reading the lengthy question! "Each of these apps should function as if they were installed at the document root of their own server." yes this is exactly what I want to achieve. I want to use multiple vhosts each with its own DocRoot, and server name (which seems to be required). So the problem is I cannot change the root, as the server guy wants to have just one domain, different apps are identified by the first level in url. I will take a look at the proxy thing and see it it resents a solution.

Comment: The documentation for setting up a reverse proxy in Apache2 is here: https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/howto/reverse_proxy.html

Comment: The example you gave is to have different host names for the same IP address. You used localhost as example, but when I do this in the actual server, does it mean I have to register for different domain names, at least different sub-domains for it to happen? If that's the case, it's out of my reach. With the same domain name, I don't know how otherwise I can distinguish between different apps hosted  under it.

Comment: The /etc/hosts file will contain all of these local domain names.  It is looked at before going out to DNS.  You simply need to edit this file and append to the 127.0.0.1 localhost line with the extra domains you want to use for the proxied hosts, ex: `127.0.0.1 localhost app1.local app2.local app1.stg.local app2.stg.local`.  All of these domains will only be available from the server, and yes, they will all resolve to 127.0.0.1.  Trying to ping app1.local from a different machine will not work.  Apache will decided which name based vhost to use when it accepts the connection on 127.0.0.1.

Comment: You could technically forgo the name based virtualhosts and use a port based approach instead, however, it will be difficult to remember what port points to which host. For example, instead of a name based vhost you would use an ip:port based vhost to listen on 127.0.0.1:8080 for app1 and listen on 127.0.0.1:8081 for app2, etc.  The benefit of the host file approach is that the vhost configuration tells you what host it is expecting instead of just an arbitrary port number like 8081.  The two approaches are functionally the same.

Comment: I never had any education over the network concepts, please bare with me: [this website](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/vhosts/name-based.html) describes the name-based vhost for apache. The machine hosting the web's /etc/hosts contains the following `153.56.34.85   localhost 153.56.34.85  team-host-loc` with made up IP and hostnames. And in apache httpd.conf there is a line saying `ServerName team.company.com:80`. I guess the ServerName is somehow mapped to the hostname somewhere, so that when I type team.comany.com in browser, it gets me the contents hosted in this machine?

Comment: So I can add extra hostnames to the IP address line in /etc/hosts, but for each of those hostnames, I need a separate VirtualHost with different ServerName in order to access each of them, correctly?

Comment: So if Apache is listening to the same ip address no many hosts, it uses the `ServerName` directive to choose which one.  This is called a name based virtualhost.  You can also configure the vhost for a unique IP and a Port combination and omit the ServerName directive.  Both concepts are outlined here: https://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/vhosts/ Please note, the hostnames you put in the /etc/hosts file will only be accessible from the server.

As for the second question, yes.  Either a unique hostname in the ServerName directive, or a unique ip:port combination for the listen directive.

Comment: You want to use the 127.0.0.1 ip in your hosts file and for the `<VirtualHost>` listen directive.  This ip is the localhost, which is bound to the loopback interface.  We are using this ip because it (and the loopback interface it is assigned to) are only available on the current machine.  You cannot access it from the outside world as it is not a public ip address, only with requests originating from the server itself, the Apache reverse proxy in this case, will reach the ip address.

Comment: I do not have permission to change the /etc/hosts files. This is not my local computer, it's the remote server I ssh to, which is also the server hosting the web. I can type the hostname in browser to get to the website (only within trusted network). The /etc/hosts file contains the server's IP (the one returned by `ip a`) not the localhost IP 127.0.0.1. I don't exactly know how these pieces play together...

Comment: You have permissions to play with your Apache configuration but not the hosts file? It sounds like you need to talk with a operations engineer, but if there is indeed a legitimate reason for this, use the port based approach.

Comment: Oh no I do not have permission for either. I was just testing apache config on my local computer. Yea the admin is kind of stubborn and wanted to keep the configuration like that. I do not have permission for anything except for probably suggesting him what rewrite rules to use. Anyways I found a way to kinda work it out. It's not perfect but it works. Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0):

I end up finding a solution with one compromise.

```
DocumentRoot "/usr/local/var/www"
Alias /app1 /usr/local/var/app1/public

<Directory "/usr/local/var/www">
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteRule ^/?$ /app1/ [R,L]
    RewriteRule (.*) /app1/$1 [R,L]
</Directory>

<VirtualHost *:80>
    <Directory "/usr/local/var/app1">
        Require all granted
        RewriteEngine On
        RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
        RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
        # calls index.php (REQUEST_URI is still the same as before)
        RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]
    </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

All relative paths can be rewritten normally.
Routes and requests will need to start with app name.

```
$router->map("GET", "/app1/hello2", SomeController);
// navigation bar. URI for another tab:
<li><a href="/app1/hello2">Hello 2</a></li>
```

If we want to have multiple versions of the app, the main thing to do is to know which version we are in so the app can send the correct request uri. This can be done by checking the REQUEST_URI and remember which version is being called when index.php is called up. Then in the request (e.g. navigation src), append it in front of the action.

There are different ways to do this, such as writing your html templates in php, so you can access php variables. I used twig so I can pass the value to the twig templates from php. But I still don't like to have all these stuff in my static code, so I decided to just get rid of the staging version.

If the project is serious enough to require a staging version, then a better suitable environment should be provided.